# instert kprobes at each system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kprobe

how a kernel probe can be inserted at each system call point? I need to track all syscalls made by a program.I managed to instrument some routines, but not the actual syscall.

thaks

Comment: Have you tried using the [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) command with your program?

Comment: I need to write a similar program but without using ptrace.

Comment: Could you explain the problem in more detail? What did you do exactly and what went wrong? Was it the problem to find the addresses of the syscall functions or to plant kprobes at these addresses? In addition, if you specify the system architecture and the kernel version, this could also help to understand the situation.